# Haskell error handling issue

Tags: haskell

I'm having this piece of code

```
expand :: Expression -> [String] -> Context -> Expression

expand expr [] context = expr

expand expr (x:xs) context = expand (subst x newExp expr) xs context
    where 
        (Just newExp) = (M.lookup x context)
```

I'm trying to throw an error if (M.lookup x context) is Nothing, is it possible to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make `expand` return `Maybe Expression`:

```
expand expr [] context = Just expr
expand expr (x:xs) context = do
    newExpr <- M.lookup x context
    expand (subst x newExpr expr) xs context
```

This is how `Maybe` is intended to be used, instead of throwing an error using `error`, you can just return a value and decide later on how to report that error to the user.  Instead of crashing your program, the idea is to use a data type that can indicate success or failure.

If you really, really want to use `error` instead, you could write

```
expand expr [] context = expr
expand expr (x:xs) context = case M.lookup x context of
    Nothing -> error $ x ++ " not found in context"
    Just newExpr -> expand (subst x newExp expr) xs context
```

But be warned that this is definitely not idiomatic Haskell, it's far better to do proper error handling, particularly when the monad instance for `Maybe` makes it so easy.